# Esteblishing a remote desktop connection from Windows 10 Home to RPi

Tags: remote, windows, desktop, xrdp

I found a bunch of tutorials on how to connect to Raspberry Pi desktop remotely. They are all together goes wth the same way:

- installing XRDP on RPi
- Just running Remote Desktop Connection app on Windows computer and connect to RPi with its IP address.

So it looks so simple. However, I don't have Remote Desktop Connection application on my PC and I can not find anything on the web. The only thing I was able to find was [Remote Desktop Connection Manager 2.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44989) which is not the thing.

I suspect that I need to have a Pro version of Windows to use this app. Is this correct?

My Windows is Home. So is there any alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is what appears to be the client app](https://www.microsoft.com/store/p/microsoft-remote-desktop/9wzdncrfj3ps). Seems to be free. 
Using a VNC viewer app such as [this one](https://www.realvnc.com/download/viewer/) rather than RDP is another alternative.

Comment: @RomanMatveev Glad it worked, have fun and welcome to Rpi Stack Exchange